# javascript loop with dynamic buttons and functions

Tags: php, javascript

In my PHP script, I have a variable that stores the length of an array in arrayLength.  I am passing that length to javascript.  I will try to keep it simple, but ideally, I am trying to provide each element in the array with it's own dynamic javascript button, each button having its own function.  I need to store these strings in an array, because user input prevents me from knowing how many elements there will be, and how many buttons/functions I will need to have.  I was previously able to get this working when I just had one button, without an array, but now I am trying to incorporate multiple dynamic buttons on one page, each belonging to a string in the array, and each button having its own function.  Is my logic that follows correct?  If you could help me, that would be much appreciated.

```
var arrayLength = "<?php echo $arrayLength; ?>";
var click = { 
click_1: function() { }
};

for (var num=2;num<=arrayLength;num++) {
var newClick = "click_" + num;
click[newClick] = function() { // controls what will happen when button is clicked };
}
```

Comment: Why are you using double quotes to specify a number? I think you need to set the `arrayLength` this way: `var arrayLength = <?php echo $arrayLength; ?>;`. ps: I don't remember if javascript autoconvert string to number.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that it would be better to provide `$arrayLength` not as a string, but as an integer, and that your comment cuts off the closing `}` of your function, your code does work, the mistake must be somewhere else.
I tried it in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ShfPh/), check the output of `console.log()`: it returns a nice object with a bunch of empty functions as properties.